# SSIS reading column as NULL when it has data

Tags: excel, ssis

I am using an EXCEL Source Component where I am reading data from an EXCEL file :

[image]

When I check the EXCEL Source Component, I find that it is reading all the values of AssignedTo as NULL :

[image]

Comment: Clearly you've done *something* wrong. We have no idea what, you haven't shown us what you're package does. I would check your mappings.

Comment: Posting your actual code/package data flow would help otherwise we dont know what your doing.

Comment: Otherwise, add breakpoints or inspect the data in the data viewer and see where the data becomes `NULL`.

Comment: I only started with the Excel Source Component and nothing else

Comment: And then, at least you have a SQL Server or OLE DB Destination, @MartinJames . So, somewhere, you've done something wrong. I would start from the end and work backwards.

Comment: If it is a CSV file use a flat file source not the excel driver.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Excel driver scans the first few rows to determine the type of the column.
And since the first cells are empty, so they are considered as NULL.
Excel defaults to only using the first 8 rows of data to do this guessing.

**Solution :**

Try increasing the number of rows it uses by modifying the `TypeGuessRows` key in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel`

OR :

Try to change the type of that column to `DTS_Str` using `DataConversion`.
Or by modifiying in directly in the EXCEL Source Component like below :

[image]